# How to show this integral equals 0?

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

**Problem:** Suppose $h:S\to\mathbb{R}$ is integrable on the set $S\subset\mathbb{R}^n$. Also $h=0$ everywhere except on a set of measure 0. How to show that $\int_S h=0$?

**Attempt:** I am trying to prove that $\underset{P}\sup\left\{L(h,P)\right\}=\underset{P}\inf\left\{U(h,P)\right\}=0$. I want to prove this by showing that for all positive $\epsilon$, I can produce a partition $P$ such that either $L(h,P)>-\epsilon$ or $U(h,P)<\epsilon$. However, I have trouble justifying that such a partition exist. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you seen the proof that a function continuous except on a set of measure zero is integrable? Almost the exact same proof works here.

Comment: I am already given that $h$ is integrable. I have trouble showing that the value of the integral is 0.

Comment: I know, but I am saying the proof that a function continuous except on a set of measure zero is integrable can be modified very slightly to give a proof of your statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $h$ vanishes everywhere in $S$ except on a set $E \subset S$ with measure $0$.

Take any partition $P$ of $S$.  If $R$ is any subrectangle, then $R$ is not a subset of $E$ since it has non-zero measure.  Hence, $h$ vanishes at some point in $R$ and $L(h,P) \leqslant 0 \leqslant U(h,P)$.

This is true for every partition $P$. Therefore,

$$\sup_{P}L(h,P) \leqslant 0 \leqslant \inf_{P} U(h,P).$$

Since the integral exists

$$\int_S h = \sup_{P}L(h,P) = \inf_{P} U(h,P)= 0.$$

Comment: Great argument, thanks!

Comment: @Letian: You're welcome. You were on the right track, but this is the most concise way to prove this for Riemann rather than Lebesgue integrals, as far as I know.